# Is there a way to log error responses from Github Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to create a bug tracker that allows me to record the error messages of the python script I run. Here is my YAML file at the moment:

```
name: Bug Tracker

 #Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push request events
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
    
  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab (for testing)
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  build:
    # Self Hosted Runner
    runs-on: windows-latest

    # Steps for tracker to get activated
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under BugTracker so the job can find it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      # Runs main script to look for 
      - name: Run File and collect bug
        id: response
        run:  |
          echo Running File...
          python script.py
          echo "${{steps.response.outputs.result}}"
```

Every time I run the workflow I can't save the error code. By save the error code, I mean for example... if the python script produces "Process completed with exit code 1." then I can save that to a txt file. I've seen cases where I could save if it runs successfully. I've thought about getting the error in the python script but I don't want to have to add the same code to every file if I don't have to. Any thoughts? Greatly appreciate any help or suggestions.

Update: I have been able to successfully use code in python to save to the txt file. However, I'm still looking to do this in Github if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: where do you want to store this txt file ?

Comment: I currently have it in the Github repository @BertrandMartel

Comment: @BertrandMartel Is this feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could :

- redirect the output to a log file while capturing the exit code
- set an output with the exit code value like:

```
echo ::set-output name=status::$status
```

- in another step, commit the log file
- in a final step, check that the exit code is success (0) otherwise exit the script with this exit code

Using `ubuntu-latest`, it would be like this:

```yaml
name: Bug Tracker

on: [push,workflow_dispatch]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      - name: Run File and collect logs
        id: run
        run:  |
          echo Running File...
          status=$(python script.py > log.txt 2>&1; echo $?)
          cat log.txt
          echo ::set-output name=status::$status
      - name: Commit log
        run: |
          git config --global user.name 'GitHub Action'
          git config --global user.email 'action@github.com'
          git add -A
          git checkout master
          git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit -am "deploy workflow logs"
          git push
      - name: Check run status
        if: steps.run.outputs.status != '0'
        run: exit "${{ steps.run.outputs.status }}"
```

On windows, I think you would need to update this part:

```sh
status=$(python script.py > log.txt 2>&1; echo $?)
cat log.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and see if it works :)

Comment: I receive an error message while running the Commit Log. Here is the error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Comment: @JordanK in the line `git checkout master` maybe replace with the current branch

Comment: `::set-output` has been deprecated! https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/

Answer (score 0):

#### My Case.

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      DIR: test
    
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'
      - run: ./sh/install.sh
        working-directory: ${{ env.DIR }}
      - id: app
        run: |
          python3 app.py
          status=$?
          echo "status=${status}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
        working-directory: ${{ env.DIR }}
      - run: exit ${{ steps.app.outputs.status }}
```